# I cant figure what really is missing in my code

Tags: react-native, donut-chart

[This is the error which i get after I run my cod in react native. I run my code in expo and I want to make a doughnut chart in react native. This is the link from which I have copied my code from.[1]

[2][https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pie][2]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pie%5D%5B2%5D)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvu8Y.jpg

Comment: This is still an open issue on github please check https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-pie/issues/41

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.